# Overriding JPA persistence unit

Tags: java, jpa

I have an empty persistenceUnit in my jar file:

```
 <persistence-unit transaction-type="JTA" name="base1">
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit transaction-type="JTA" name="base2">
    </persistence-unit>
```

My idea is to replace the empty persistenceUnit by a full persistenceUnit with properties and classes in my main project, like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="base1" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>br.com.myproject.MyClass</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                      value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

But when i try to start server i got the following error:

```
 Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0038: Falha ao adicionar o serviço da unidade de persistência para base1
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.persistenceunit.myproject#base1.__FIRST_PHASE__ is already registered"}}
```

Is there any way to override the persistenceUnit ?

Comment: is there a reason why you marked a jta-looking like resource as non-jta-data-source?

Comment: NO, this is just a mistake i will edit my post.

Comment: and you packaging is done right? no duplicated persistence.xml in your JAR/WAR etc.?
I'd also suggest removing not needed PUs like "base2".

Comment: I need PU "base2" empty in my JAR, beucase i create a @PersistenceContext with "base2", and i need override this in some projects. So i need duplicate PU's

Comment: Did you check what's inside your persistence.xml when you unzip your Jar?

Comment: Yes, exist a persistence.xml with empty data, because i putted there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137448/discussion-between-the86freak-and-scientist).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to dynamically override your persistence.xml, this might be best done during building.

my personal warning: it sounds like a configuration-hell to me and I'd rather suggest using a container-managed JNDI approach here.

But anyway:
Use 2 maven profiles. 
And if you activate profile1, then persistence.xml from profile1 will be added at the right place. and if you activate profile2 persistence.xml from profile2 will be taken.

therefore use the copy-resources-mojo for maven. 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

If just the values of parameters change, and not the whole structure,
then you can also just "filter" and replace strings during maven-processes 
then you would define properties in the profiles. 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

You can also add a basic persistence.xml to your project as a default file. So if no maven-profile is activated, this one will be used. (even though it might happen, that the app doesn't work as expected, if the data-resource is not configured correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides an interface JpaVendorAdapter which allows to plug in any JPA vendor specific configuration through Spring Java config or XML configuration during application startup.

You can create an EntityManagerFactory instance with LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and any implementation classes of JpaVendorAdapter such as HibernateJpaVendorAdapter, EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter or OpenJpaVendorAdapter.

I believe you don't even need to define the empty persistence unit in persistence.xml if your application used Spring.

Below is the sample on how to create EntityManagerFactory with Spring Java config:

```
    @Inject 
    private DataSource base1DataSource;

    @Inject 
    private DataSource base2DataSource;

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory base1EntityManagerFactory()
            throws IOException, NamingException {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean containerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAMES");
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJtaDataSource(base1DataSource);
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(loadBase1JpaProperties());
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("base1");
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory base2EntityManagerFactory()
            throws IOException, NamingException {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean containerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAMES");
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJtaDataSource(base2DataSource);
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(loadBase2JpaProperties());
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("base2");
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties loadBase1JpaProperties() throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("base1-persistence.properties");

        return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties loadBase2JpaProperties() throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("base2-persistence.properties");

        return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
    }
```

Please refer to the following URL for additional info on what you can override to your persistence.xml :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to declare your persistent unit in a superclass and you want to define the persistent unit in a explicit project. If true you could use a JNDI approch like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="JTA">

    <jta-data-source>java:/myDS</jta-data-source>

    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>


    <jar-file>Persistence.jar</jar-file>

    <properties>

        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:app/applicationEntitymanager"/>  
        <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

on the other side you can acces the Entitymanager with:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:app/applicationEntitymanager")
protected EntityManager em;
```